Message: stale element reference: stale element not found in the current frame
Мне нужно что бы скрипт нажал кнопку войти, но при попытке ее найти по id он выдает ошибку
Message: stale element reference: stale element not found in the current frame
Вот мой код
from get_chrome_driver import GetChromeDriver
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import gg

get_driver = GetChromeDriver()
get_driver.install()


# disable webdriver mode
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

# driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'https://techreg.gov.kz/index/#'

# Use the installed ChromeDriver with Selenium
try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'details-button').click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'proceed-link').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
#ошибка выходит при выполнении данной строчки
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'button_start_work').click()

    time.sleep(5)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()


Вот Полный код ошибки
Message: stale element reference: stale element not found in the current frame
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.123); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7364D7032+63090]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF736442C82]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7362DEC65]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7362E3D21]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7362E6159]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7362E6200]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF736326B1E]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF73631C447]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF736346FDA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF73631A00A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7363471F0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF736363412]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF736346D83]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7363183A8]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF736319441]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7368D25AD+4238317]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF73690F70D+4488525]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7369079EF+4456495]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7365B0576+953270]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF73644E54F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF736449224]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF73644935B]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF736439B94]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFEE2E77344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFEE3BA26B1+33]


Process finished with exit code 0


В данный момент я пробовал найти ее через class, css_selector, id но ошибка одна и та же "Элемент не может быть найден именно в тот момент, когда вы пытались его найти"
Понимаю что с первого взгляда кажется что ошибка из-за версии браузера и его драйвера, но на других сайтах все работает. Chrome 123.0.6312.123 | Chromedriver 123.0.6312.122
Вот Кнопка что я пытаюсь найти
<button data-cy="button_start_work" title="" id="button_start_work" class=" uk-button margined uk-button-default techreg_green_btn  fonts" style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); z-index: 0; box-sizing: border-box; direction: ltr; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">Войти</button> 

Вы пишите "Вот Полный код ошибки". Но это не так. Нет самого главного - указания на оператор, вызвавший ошибку. Ни номера строки, ни номера оператора. В системном сообщении Вы отрезали первую (самую главную) часть.  Кроме того, приведённый текст программы тоже не полон. В сообщении об ошибке сказано, что был неудачный поиск по тексту {"selector":"Войти"}. В тексте этого оператора нет. Подправьте свой вопрос.

Могу только предположить, что ошибка о "Элемент не может быть найден именно в тот момент, когда вы пытались его найти" означает, что либо этот элемент ещё не подгрузился, либо он невидим в данное время (вне окна, закрыт другим элементом, ну и т.д)  По любому, надо использовать нечто вроде "container.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button').click()"

@Sergey Спасибо что заметили ошибку в вопросе, уже подправил. Ошибку он выдает мне через Exception поэтому там привязки к строчке нет, я пометил комментарием проблемную строчку. Спасибо за рекомендацию, попробую!

Попробуйте вместо
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'button_start_work').click()

написать нечто вроде
# Говорим ожидающему объекту, что ждём готовности кнопки
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
btn = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'btn')
element.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(btn)).click() # По готовности выполняем клик


Возможно, необходимо переключиться на другое окно фрейма. Посмотрите, может у вас несколько iframe в коде? Вот код для переключения: driver.switchTo().frame(1);

В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению; на данный момент, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора. — из очереди проверок
